# Web API Business Layer Architecture and its responsibilities

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, architecture, asp.net-web-api2, business-logic-layer

I have following classes in my web api business layer, i was wondering if GatewayService class should be in Business layer or should i put that in separate project called BusinessService? because its not being directly called in controller class and it doesn't depend on data repository ?

**Business Layer**

- GatewayService (referencing < dll file > methods and making calls to external web service and returning list of transactions)
- UserService (returns a list of all users from production database using < repository class > from data layer)
- TransactionService ( get a list of all users from < UserService > and then get all their transactions from < Gateway Service > )

Here is what Transaction Controller doing;

**Transaction Controller**

> Getting a list of users from < UserService >
>
> Passing a list of Users to < TransactionService > which will then return a list of user transactions
>
> Passing a list of all transactions to < TransactionService > to process them through a data repository class

Answer (score 1):

In case of **N-Layer** architecture

`TransactionService` should be in an `Application` layer, then your `GatewayService` can be part of the `Business Layer`.

[image]

In case of **Clean Architecture**

`GatewayService` should be part of `Presistence` or `Infrastracture` layer so it is not a `business` layer (here `domain` and `application`).

[image]

Comment: i have never seen a Application Layer in WEB API project.

Comment: It does not matter if it is WEB API, MVC, or a ConsoleApp. It is about structure of your modules and finding a middle ground between speed and efficiency. In case of n-layer check the ABP project, in case of Clean Architecture JasonGT/NorthwindTraders project on github

Comment: What about User Service? would this stay in Business Layer?

Comment: In n-layered yes it is.

Comment: Can i call my Application layer a ApplicationService ?

Comment: Sorry this is gooing too deply into details. I also do not know what is the responsability of the ApplicationService. Answere contains enough key words for doing your own research about those.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a part of the business layer. The business layer is where you would implement the external requirements for your system fx. logistics and so. Which falls under the same category as your gateway service.

[image]